# What are block-based animation methods in iPhone OS 4.0?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiview, core-animation

I am trying to implement a game using the iPhone OS 4.0 (iOS4?) SDK. In the previous versions of the SDK, I've been using the [UIView beginAnimations:context:] and [UIView commitAnimations] to create some animations. However, when I look at the documentation of the functions in 4.0, I see this comment.

> Use of this method is discouraged in
>   iPhone OS 4.0 and later. You should
>   use the block-based animation methods
>   instead.

You can find it here:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/commitAnimations

My question is, what are block-based animations in iPhone OS 4.0? I though that the beginAnimations:context: and commitAnimations functions were used to create animation blocks..

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you follow that link and scroll up a bit, you will see animate methods new to ios4.

```
animateWithDuration:animations:
animateWithDuration:animations:completion:
animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:
```

There are also some related transition methods.  For each of these, the animations argument is a [block object](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Block.html):

> animations
>   A block object containing
>   the changes to commit to the views.
>   This is where you programmatically
>   change any animatable properties of
>   the views in your view hierarchy. This
>   block takes no parameters and has no
>   return value. This parameter must not
>   be NULL.

[Block objects](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502) are part of [Concurrent Programming](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html)

Answer (score 117):

I have posted an example in my [blog](http://ho.race.hk/blog/?p=304):

```
    CGPoint originalCenter = icon.center;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
            animations:^{ 
                CGPoint center = icon.center;
                center.y += 60;
                icon.center = center;
            } 
            completion:^(BOOL finished){

                [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                        animations:^{ 
                            icon.center = originalCenter;
                        } 
                        completion:^(BOOL finished){
                            ;
                        }];

            }];
```

The above code will animate a UIImageView* (icon) in a 2-second animation. Once completed, another animation will move the icon back to it’s original position.

Comment: Why not use `[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];` in animation block and `self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;` in completion block? :)

Comment: how can i repeat this animation ?

Comment: that will repeat only num of times given. Well found solution. thanks for response.

Answer (score 20):

Here's a very simple example. The code just fades out an UIView and hides it after the animation is done:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                      delay:0.0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut 
                 animations:^ {
                     bgDisplay.alpha = 0.0;
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     bgDisplay.hidden = YES;
                 }];
```

or in different formatting:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^ {
    bgDisplay.alpha = 0.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    bgDisplay.hidden = YES;
}];
```

Comment: Just a heads up that the option listed above is deprecated in 6.0 - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Comment: What exactly is deprecated in 6.0? Neither UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut nor animateWithDuration is marked as deprecated!