# Moving UIAnimation back and forth along the x axis

Tags: ios

I could get the UIImage to move just a bit to the x -axis to the right and back  to original position.

```
 -(void) uiview_anim
 {

[UIView beginAnimations:@"Move" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:3];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
CGPoint a;

     a.x=finger.frame.origin.x;


a.x=a.x+10;              

finger.center=a;


[UIView commitAnimations];  
}
```

It also move the Y direction too, but I didn't specify that.   I need it to snap back to the original position once moved.  Finger is the UIImageView I am working on.

Comment: You should use the [animation based on blocks][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126833/what-are-block-based-animation-methods-in-iphone-os-4-0